# How to get value from database

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

I am creating a social network. The users can have a verified account. If the value of the column `verified_user` is 1 that means the user is verified and I want to echo `verified`. If the value is 0 I want to echo `not verified`. I have a method that is suppose to get all of this data and an object that is suppose to echo what the method gives. But it keeps on echoing `Not verified` even though the value says 1. Can someone tell me what's wrong ?

```
public function verifiedUser($user_to) {

    $query = $this->con->prepare("SELECT verified_user FROM users WHERE username = ?");
    $query->bind_param("s", $this->user['username']);
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($verified_user);
    $query_result = $query->get_result();

    if ($verified_user == 1) {

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;
    }

}
```

---

```
if($logged_in_user_obj->verifiedUser($username)) {

    echo "Verified";
} else{

        echo "Not Verified";
    }
```

I also tried `num_rows` but that gave me the same results I'm getting now.

Comment: What's the point of passing `$user_to` but binding another variable? Also `var_dump($verified_user)` to see its value.

Comment: I changed the parameter to `$username` The var dump comes back ass null

Comment: it should be `$query->bind_param("s", $user_to);`

Comment: then simply `return (bool) $verified_user` no need for the superfluous if/else

Comment: @LawrenceCherone still getting the same result. Not verified

Comment: Hello any answer ?

Comment: Where do you fetch anything from the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the result stored in `$query_result` or get the actual value by binding to a variable and fetching it.

If you want to use `get_result()` then do:

```
public function verifiedUser(string $user_to): bool {
    $query = $this->con->prepare("SELECT verified_user FROM users WHERE username = ?");
    $query->bind_param("s", $user_to);
    $query->execute();
    $query_result = $query->get_result();
    $row = $query_result->fetch_assoc();

    if ($row && $row['verified_user'] == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you want to use `bind_result` then do this:

```
public function verifiedUser(string $user_to): bool {
    $query = $this->con->prepare("SELECT verified_user FROM users WHERE username = ?");
    $query->bind_param("s", $user_to);
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($verified_user);
    $query->fetch();

    return $verified_user == 1;
}
```

Comment: I just tried both of them and now it says Verified even if I'm not verified

Comment: What is the value of `$verified_user`? What is the value of `$user_to`? Are you sure you are selecting the right record?

Comment: Yeah I'm positive. `verified_user` `tinyint(1)` only values it can hold is `0(false)` or `1(true)`

Comment: I see. It gives me the value of the current user logged in. I'm trying to check if any user is verified on their profile

Comment: Then you need to provide a different argument to `verifiedUser()`

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to figure that one out.

Comment: I figured it out.